# Can I define an OCaml function that returns itself?

Tags: ocaml

In Scheme, I can write a function:

```
(define (eat-line line)
  eat-line)
```

Which I could use in a loop like:

```
(define (loop op)
  (let ((line (read-line))
    (loop (op line))))
```

In OCaml I tried to define a function:

```
let rec eat_line line = eat_line
```

But I got the error:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a -> 'b
   but an expression was expected of type 'b
   The type variable 'b occurs inside 'a -> 'b
```

Is it possible to define such a function in OCaml, or is it prevented by the type system? If so, why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define the function if you specify `-rectypes` when you run the interpreter or compiler:

```
$ ocaml -rectypes
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# let rec eat_line line = eat_line;;
val eat_line : 'b -> 'a as 'a = <fun>

# eat_line "yes" "indeed";;
- : string -> 'a as 'a = <fun>
# eat_line 3 5 7;;
- : int -> 'a as 'a = <fun>
```

Types like this (recursive or cyclic types) are not allowed by default because they are very often the result of coding errors.

Comment: Thanks for the astoundingly prompt answer!

Comment: For the readers: this was discussed 15 years ago: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/caml-list/2040.html